# php str_replace change same text inside string with diffrent text

Tags: php, html

This is text:

```
$string = "This is my car. 
my car.
Look my car.";
```

I'd like to add text before and after every sentence:
so my result would be:

```
SOME-TEXT This is my car. SOME-TEXT
SOME-TEXT my car. SOME-TEXT
SOME-TEXT Look my car. SOME-TEXT
```

I'm trying like this:

```
$string = str_replace("my car", "SOME-TEXT my car SOME-TEXT", $string);
```

but I get result:

```
<p>This is SOME-TEXT my car. SOME-TEXT</p> 
<td>SOME-TEXT my car. SOME-TEXT</td>
<h1>Look SOME-TEXT my car. SOME-TEXT<h1>
```

which is not what I want!!!

Any idea ?!

Comment: Your input is 'pure', no HTML string (with new line as separator, between sentences, which can be used, for explode()), but your output is HTML... Could you provide context, maybe there are better ways?

Comment: This text here is just an example output. I'd like to add SOME-TEXT, before and after some text on html page. Any html page can be used as an example. Can you provide example on some simple html page. Problem is when some string (in this case --my car-- for example) is in many sentences.

Comment: Well... you need HTML parsing in this case... There are many possible inputs (and outputs), 'simple example' will not help in other cases...

Comment: OK. Can you provide some example. Let take for example this page http://www.test-net.org. How can I add SOME-TEXT before and after every sentece on this page?

Comment: One possible way: Use this simple library - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/, get desired element(s) text, and manipulate it.

Comment: I'm usig it for extracting text from html page, but how to change it with that library. Can you provide some peace of code, like an example?

Comment: https://eval.in/448621 - here it is.... To get text for between EVERY sentence, explode plaintext by limiter (dot)...

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = str_replace("my car.", "my car. SOME-TEXT", $string);
```

Comment: SOME-TEXT This is my car. SOME-TEXT
SOME-TEXT my car. SOME-TEXT
SOME-TEXT Look my car. SOME-TEXT This code don't provide me that result.

Answer (score 0):

This achieves what you want:

```
$string = "This is my car. 
my car.
Look my car.";
define('SOME_TEXT', 'SOME-TEXT');
define('BEG', SOME_TEXT . ' ');
define('END', ' ' . SOME_TEXT);
$result = BEG . str_replace("\n", END . "\n" . BEG, $string). END;
```